# From world coordinates to camera coordinates

Tags: camera

I have a 3D point in the world coordinates, (-140,-500,0) where z is the upwards vector, x is the depth and y is the horizontal 
Now I want to convert this point to camera coordinates 
I know that I need to calculate rotation matrix and translation 
I have roll pitch and yaw and the camera position
I want to know if I am calculating the point in the camera coordinates correctly

```
    //ax, ay and az are the position of the point in the real world 
    //cx, cy and cz are the position of the camera 
    //67.362312316894531 is pitch 
    //89.7135009765625 is roll 
    //0.033716827630996704 is yaw 
    double x = ax - cx; 
    double y = ay -cy;
    double z = az - cz;
    double cosx = cos(67.362312316894531);
    double sinx = sin(67.362312316894531);
    double cosy = cos(89.7135009765625);
    double siny = sin(89.7135009765625);
    double cosz = cos(0.033716827630996704);
    double sinz = sin(0.033716827630996704);
    dx = cosy * (sinz * y + cosz * x) - siny * z;
    dy = sinx * (cosy * z + siny * (sinz * y + cosz * x)) + cosx * (cosz * y - sinz * x);
    dz = cosx * (cosy * z + siny * (sinz * y + cosz * x)) - sinx * (cosz * y - sinz * x);
```

I know that the other method is to calculate the rotation matrix

```
    //where yp is pitch, thet is roll and k is yaw 
    double rotxm[9] = { 1,0,0,0,cos(yp),-sin(yp),0,sin(yp),cos(yp) };
    double rotym[9] = { cos(thet),0,sin(thet),0,1,0,-sin(thet),0,cos(thet) };
    double rotzm[9] = { cos(k),-sin(k),0,sin(k),cos(k),0,0,0,1};
    cv::Mat rotx = Mat{ 3,3,CV_64F,rotxm };
    cv::Mat roty = Mat{ 3,3,CV_64F,rotym };
    cv::Mat rotz = Mat{ 3,3,CV_64F,rotzm };
    cv::Mat rotationm = rotz * roty * rotx;
```

my question are these two methods correct? or at least on of them.. how can I make sure of that

Comment: Your second method is correct (if your rpc values are correct and their order is correct), additionally you should create a 4x4 transformation matrix and you can easily transform an arbitrary point from world coordinates to camera coordinates and vice-versa.

Comment: @unlut Thank you very much

Comment: @unlut so is this correct for z as the upward axis and x as the depth axis? .. I just want to make sure of that

Comment: @sumala Well honestly I don't use terms "roll, pitch, yaw" for same reason, people not always consistent which term represent rotation around which axis. I prefer "rotation around x axis is 53" etc... But when I look it up here http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node102.html, it says "roll" is rotation around x axis unlike your code where its used for calculating y rotation.

Comment: @unlut thank you very much .. yes I think I mixed the names ..it was my fault